# how to extract all occurrences of same element one at a time from an xml using shell script

Tags: xml, sed, sh

I am new to shell Scripting.
I am looking to parse the xml and extract every occurrence of same element one at a time.
for Example my xml looks like.

```
<domain>
    <values>required details</values>
    <logs>logging Information</logs>
    <details>
        <server>server1</server>
        <basicDetails>first detail</basicDetails>
        <name>serverName</name>
        <serverDomain>domain1</serverDomain>
    </details>
    <details>
        <server>server2</server>
        <basicDetails>second detail</basicDetails>
        <name>serverName2</name>
        <serverDomain>domain2</serverDomain>
    </details>
    <details>
        <server>server3</server>
        <basicDetails>details listed</basicDetails>
        <name>serverName3</name>
        <serverDomain>domain3</serverDomain>
    </details>
    <details>
        <server>server1</server>
        <basicDetails>the detail</basicDetails>
        <name>serverName4</name>
        <serverDomain>domain4</serverDomain>
    </details>
</domain>
```

I want to iterate all the elements under details(including details tag) one at a time and validate the values

now I am using the below code but it is giving me all the elements of details instead one at a time

```
Details="$(echo "cat //*[local-name()='domain']/*[local-name()='details']" | xmllint --shell my.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d')"
```

i want to use for loop and pass the elements of one  tag at a time

Comment: Can you add sample output for your example

Comment: It is not at all clear what you intend to do. Whatever it is, `sed` and `sh` are unlikely to be the right tools.

Comment: @Chet from the above xml I wanted to retrieve the second occurrence of details tag leaving everything else.
like :
<details>
        <server>server2</server>
        <basicDetails>second detail</basicDetails>
        <name>serverName2</name>
        <serverDomain>domain2</serverDomain>
    </details>